# Batch script for moving files doesn't work

Tags: batch-file

I tried to create a batch script which will move a folder created on a previous day from a directory to another.

I've looked at all the trends and tried to do it myself, and I managed to do something, but it still doesn't do what I would like.

In a directory, I will always have 2 folders. Every day I need to go and copy the folder created on the previous day to the new location at 3 am in the morning. I've tried all the option with the MAXAGE, MINAGE, MAXLAD, and MINLAD but probably I don't understand how this works!

```
@echo off

/MINAGE:1 :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than 1 days/date.

set MyLogFile=%date%

set MyLogFile=%MyLogFile:/=-%

robocopy /log+:"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\%mylogfile%.txt" /TEE C:\Users\Desktop\Test\try1\n1 C:\Users\Desktop\Test\try2\n2 /MOVE /E /MINAGE:1

robocopy /log+:"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\%mylogfile%.txt" /TEE C:\Users\Desktop\Test\try3\n3 C:\Users\Desktop\Test\try4\n4 /MOVE /E /MINAGE:1
```

At the moment it moves all the files from `try1/n1` to `try2/n2` no matter how old or new is the folder.

The expected result would be from `try1/n1` in which I have 2 folders (one created yesterday and one today) to move into `try2/n2` only the folder created yesterday!

Comment: I think the `/MINAGE` option only regards the last modification date of files but not the creation date of directories...

Comment: From what I read MAXAGE and MINAGE refers to the creation date of the file, and MAXLAD and MINLAD refer to date modified. Anyway, I've tried with all of them and still didn't get the expected result.

Comment: These `robocopy` filters do not regard *directories*, only *files*, that's the issue here. Seems you have to pre-filter your directories somehow else. For instance, `dir /A:D /T:C` could retrieve creation dates of directories, but in a locale-dependent manner, unfortunately. You could use `wmic FSDir where "Name='C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\try1\\n1'" get CreationDate` to get locale-independent dates, but this is more complicated to handle. Or you switch to another language that features easier date handling...